# Как в плагине Woocommerce правильно организовать доп. опции для вариативного товара?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть вариативный товар. У него можно выбрать размер и цена меняется в зависимости от него. Нужно сделать доп опции чекбоксами, чтобы цена также динамически складывалась и отображалась. Есть идеи как это можно примерно сделать и чтобы потом в админке можно было поменять цену для доп опций? Может как-то через атрибуты можно?

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь [WOOCOMMERCE. КАК СОЗДАТЬ ВАРИАТИВНЫЙ ТОВАР](https://saphali.com/woocommerce-kak-sozdat-variativnyj-tovar.html) описано создание вариативности товаров, если используются простые (процентную наценку я там не видел) методы установки цен на товары  в зависимости от варианта то этот вариант подойдет.